# How to add gauge or progress bar to ObjectListView wxPython?

Tags: python, wxpython, objectlistview

How to add gauge or progress bar to ObjectListView in wxPython?

You can see "Upload Status" column need to be with gauge or progress bar.

[image: Music UPloader]

Comment: maybe you can be more specific in your question? not sure what a gauge or progress bar has to do with a list of choosable items. do you want a progress bar while it's populating items?

Comment: I'm trying to add progress bar or gauge by using this [ObjectViewList](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/python/gettingStarted.html) wrapper to wx.ListCtrl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating a download-type manager application and want to show the progress of each item in the ListCtrl, then I would recommend the UltimateListCtrl. It is a widget written in pure Python and the wxPython demo for it already shows an example of how to add a progress bar to it.

The ObjectListView is a wrapper of the wx.ListCtrl. I don't believe the ListCtrl supports adding other widgets to it very easily. You would probably have to create a custom widget that is a combination of the two if you decided you didn't want to use the UltimateListCtrl.